# About divergence and curl from diagram

Tags: multivariable-calculus, divergence-operator

[image]

So given picture I have to check whether divergence and curl is positive, negative or zero.

So I check vector field at some point ; for figure b I can see that vector field goes outward so divergence is positive but for figure a I am not able to predict. Also how to conclude about curl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to doing this is to model the vector fields by rotating them clockwise by 45-degrees.  If you do this, then it’s not a bad approximation to say that

$$
F_1(x,y)=(y,0)\hspace{2pc}  F_2(x,y)=(x, 0).
$$

Even if it’s not exact, using the above vector fields can still give you the qualitative details about curl and divergence.  Clearly the divergence of $F_1$ is zero while that of $F_2$ is positive.  For curl, the only term that would appear would $\nabla\times F=\left(\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y}\right)\hat{z}$.  From this you can clearly see that the curl of $F_1$ will be positive and that of $F_2$ will be zero.

**Showing Curl/Divergence are Rotationally Invariant**

We can demonstrate that the curl and divergence are rotationally-invariant properties using these particular vector fields.  The vector fields are actually modeled after the following vector fields by rotating by 45 degrees ccw:
$$
\widetilde{F}_1(x,y) = (y,0) \hspace{3pc} \widetilde{F}_2  = (x,0).
$$

If $R$ is a rotation matrix (i.e. orthogonal with determinant 1) then the correct way to transform a vector field $\widetilde{F}$ into another is via the formula: $F(v) = R\widetilde{F}\left (R^Tv\right )$, which is a result obtained from [this post on math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912070/rotating-vector-functions).  The matrix $R$ that we want to rotate in the plane by 45 degrees is given by:
$$
R \;\; = \;\; \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
1/\sqrt{2} & - 1/\sqrt{2} \\
1/\sqrt{2} &  1/\sqrt{2} \\
\end{array} \right ]
$$

The vector field $F_1$ in your prompt can then be found as:
\begin{eqnarray*}
F_1(x,y) & = & \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
1/\sqrt{2} & - 1/\sqrt{2} \\
1/\sqrt{2} &  1/\sqrt{2} \\
\end{array} \right ] \widetilde{F}_1 \left (\left [ \begin{array}{cc}
1/\sqrt{2} &  1/\sqrt{2} \\
-1/\sqrt{2} &  1/\sqrt{2} \\
\end{array} \right ]\left [ \begin{array}{c}
x \\ y \\
\end{array} \right ] \right ) \\
& = & \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
1/\sqrt{2} & - 1/\sqrt{2} \\
1/\sqrt{2} &  1/\sqrt{2} \\
\end{array} \right ] \widetilde{F}_1 \left (\left [ \begin{array}{c}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(y+x) \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(y-x) \\
\end{array} \right ] \right ) \\
& = & \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
1/\sqrt{2} & - 1/\sqrt{2} \\
1/\sqrt{2} &  1/\sqrt{2} \\
\end{array} \right ]\left [ \begin{array}{c}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(y-x) \\ 0 \\
\end{array} \right ] \\
& = & \frac{1}{2}\left [ \begin{array}{c}
y-x \\ y-x \\
\end{array} \right ].
\end{eqnarray*}

Now, let's compare the curls and divergences of $F_1(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}(y-x,y-x)$ and $\widetilde{F}_1(x,y) = (y,0)$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\nabla \times F_1 & = & \left | \begin{array}{ccc}
\hat{i} & \hat{j} & \hat{k} \\
\partial_x & \partial_y & \partial_z \\
\frac{1}{2}(y-x) & \frac{1}{2}(y-x) & 0 \\
\end{array} \right |\;\; =\;\; \left (-\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\right )\hat{k} \;\; =\;\; -\hat{k} \\
\nabla \times \widetilde{F}_1 & = & \left | \begin{array}{ccc}
\hat{i} & \hat{j} & \hat{k} \\
\partial_x & \partial_y & \partial_z \\
y & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array} \right | \;\; =\;\; - \hat{k} \\
\nabla\cdot F_1 & = & \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{1}{2}(y-x) + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \frac{1}{2}(y-x) \;\; =\;\; -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \;\; =\;\; 0 \\
\nabla \cdot \widetilde{F}_1 & = & \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(y) + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(0) \;\; =\;\; 0.
\end{eqnarray*}

Similar computations follow for $F_2$ and $\widetilde{F}_2$.

Comment: Why divergence is zeo in first figure and positive in second?

Comment: @mathsstudent Look up the definition of divergence and apply it to the vector fields in my answer.

Comment: How to be sure that rotation does not change sign of curl, flux and divergence?

Comment: How to be sure about rotation does not change divergence and curl?

Comment: @mathsstudent Please see my edits.