# Rotate vector field around the x axis by 90 degrees clockwise

Tags: rotations, vector-fields

Consider the vector field in Cartesian coordinates, $\mathbf F(x,y,z) = -y \, \hat{\mathbf x} + x \, \hat{\mathbf y} + 0 \, \hat{\mathbf z}$. The arrows curl around the positive $z$ axis (*i.e.* the "axis" of the field is in the $z$ direction), with the direction determined by the right hand rule, as shown in the following figure.

[image: Plot of F field]

*Figure 1. Plot of $\mathbf F$.*

---

**My question**

I want to rotate $\mathbf F$ such that the arrows curl around the positive $y$ axis (*i.e.* the "axis" of the field should now be in the $y$ direction), as shown in the following figure. Let's call this desired new field as $\mathbf G$. **How can I achieve this?**

[image: Plot of G field]

*Figure 2. Plot of $\mathbf G$.*

---

**My attempt #1**

Since we want to rotate the axis of the field $\mathbf F$ from the $z$ axis to the $y$ axis, I think to achieve that we should rotate $\mathbf F$ around the $x$ axis by 90° clockwise (with the unit vector $\hat{\mathbf x}$ pointing towards us). And **[as we know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions)**, to rotate a vector or point in 3D around the $x$ axis we use the following transformation matrix:

$\mathbf R = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos \theta &  -\sin \theta \\
0 & \sin \theta  &  \cos \theta \\
\end{bmatrix},$

with $\theta$ measured counterclockwise. In our case we choose $\theta = -90^\circ$ (negative because we want to rotate clockwise), so:

$\mathbf R = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 &  1 \\
0 & -1  &  0 \\
\end{bmatrix}.$

Premultiplying $\mathbf F$ by the above matrix, we get the vector field $\mathbf H(x,y,z) = -y \, \hat{\mathbf x} + 0 \, \hat{\mathbf y} - x \, \hat{\mathbf z}$. The plot of $\mathbf H$ is the following, and as we can see it's not the desired $\mathbf G$ field.

[image: Plot of H field]

*Figure 3. Plot of $\mathbf H$.*

After playing around, I found $\mathbf G$ must actually be $\mathbf G(x,y,z) = z \, \hat{\mathbf x} + 0 \, \hat{\mathbf y} - x \, \hat{\mathbf z}$, as shown in figure 2. **Why?**

---

**EDIT: My attempt #2**

I found **[this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/912070/582457)**. According to the asker and **[John Hughes' answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/912129/582457)**, the formula to compute $\mathbf G$ from $\mathbf F$ should be:

${\mathbf G} = {\mathbf R} \, {\mathbf F} \left( {\mathbf v}_1, {\mathbf v}_2, {\mathbf v}_3 \right),$

where:

${\mathbf v}_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix} \cdot {\mathbf R}^T \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ \end{bmatrix},$

${\mathbf v}_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix} \cdot {\mathbf R}^T \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ \end{bmatrix},$

${\mathbf v}_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \cdot {\mathbf R}^T \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ \end{bmatrix}.$

Using those four equations, and Wolfram Mathematica for the computations, I indeed get $\mathbf G(x,y,z) = z \, \hat{\mathbf x} + 0 \, \hat{\mathbf y} - x \, \hat{\mathbf z}$, as shown in the following figure.

[image: Mathematica computation]

*Figure 4. Computation of ${\mathbf G}$ with Mathematica.*

So I've answered my first question ("*How can I achieve this?*"), but I'd still appreciate if someone could answer my second question, which now is: **Why do the formulas from John Hughes work?**

Comment: What was $-y$ is now $z$ after rotation of coordinate axes. So unless you change $-y$ to $z$, the vector field will not curl around y-axis.

Comment: @MathLover Is there a general formula to make the rotation I want for any 3D vector field? I searched on Google but didn't find any.