# Rotating and Translating a Vector Field

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, coordinate-systems, rotations, transformation

I have an explicit expression for a vector field with components ($u',v'$) in some local coordinate frame ($x',y'$). The picture on the left below shows an example, where the vector field is constant in some direction inside a rectangle, and is zero everywhere outside the rectangle. Now I would like to calculate what the field would be in some laboratory frame of reference ($x,y$), in which I have positioned the object somewhere else (a translation by ($x_0,y_0$) and rotation by angle $\theta$ counterclockwise), as shown on the right:

[image]

It seems from trying to work it out on paper that I need to do the following steps:

1. First take my lab coordinates ($x,y$) and see how they are represented in the object's local frame ($x',y'$). This is done by applying a rotation matrix
   \begin{align}
       \begin{pmatrix}
              x' \\
              y'
            \end{pmatrix} &=      \begin{pmatrix}
              \cos\theta & \sin\theta \\
              -\sin\theta & \cos\theta
            \end{pmatrix}   \begin{pmatrix}
              x \\
              y
            \end{pmatrix}
     \end{align}

(note that confusingly to me this actually seems to be the *transpose* (or inverse?) of [the rotation matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix?wprov=sfla1) for a counterclockwise rotation by angle $\theta$.)

2. Then use these coordinates to calculate my field components using my analytic expression to get ($u'(x',y'),v'(x',y')$).
3. Finally, it seems I need to transform the resulting vectors by applying a rotation matrix again (the inverse of the original one this time):
   \begin{align}
       \begin{pmatrix}
              u \\
              v
            \end{pmatrix} &=      \begin{pmatrix}
              \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\
              \sin\theta & \cos\theta
            \end{pmatrix}   \begin{pmatrix}
              u' \\
              v'
            \end{pmatrix}
     \end{align}

This is somehow "projecting" the first components back into the lab frame?

My questions are basically: Is this line of thought correct? Is it expected that I should need to apply rotation matrix twice when transforming a vector field - one being the inverse of the other?

---

Numerical example

Here is some Matlab code which shows that the steps above seem to work:

[image]

```
x0 = 3;     % Translation offsets
y0 = 4;
theta = 40; % Rotation counterclockwise around z axis (in degrees)

x = linspace(-10,10,1000); y = x;[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y); % Laboratory frame grid

[U,V] = f(X,Y,x0,y0,theta);  % Calculate vector function

imagesc(x,y,sqrt(U.^2+V.^2)) % Plot magnitude of vector function
quiver(X,Y,U,V)              % Plot arrows of vector function

function [U,V] = f(X,Y,x0,y0,theta)
    [Xr,Yr] = transform_coordinates(X,Y,x0,y0,theta);
    [Ur,Vr] = calculate_components(Xr,Yr);
    [U,V] = project_components_back(Ur,Vr,theta);
end

function [Xr,Yr] = transform_coordinates(X,Y,x0,y0,theta)
    X = X-x0;
    Y = Y-y0;
    R = [+cosd(theta) +sind(theta); 
         -sind(theta) +cosd(theta)]; 
    rotXY = [X(:) Y(:)]*R.';
    Xr = reshape(rotXY(:,1), size(X,1), []);
    Yr = reshape(rotXY(:,2), size(Y,1), []);
end

function [U,V] = project_components_back(Ur,Vr,theta)
    R = [+cosd(theta) -sind(theta); 
         +sind(theta) +cosd(theta)]; 
    rotUV = [Ur(:) Vr(:)]*R.';
    U = reshape(rotUV(:,1), size(Ur,1), []);
    V = reshape(rotUV(:,2), size(Vr,1), []);
end

function [Ur,Vr] = calculate_components(Xr,Yr)
    % Some operation which represents my function (in this case, create a rectangle)
    lx = 3; ly = 5; % Rectangle side lengths
    Ur = zeros(size(Xr));
    Vr = Ur;
    Ur(abs(Xr)<lx/2 & abs(Yr)<ly/2) = 0;
    Vr(abs(Xr)<lx/2 & abs(Yr)<ly/2) = 1; % Vector field points along rectangle axis
end
```

Comment: It makes sense that you have to rotate things twice. One for the coordinates of the points from which your arrows start, and another to rotate the direction of the arrows themselves. As for the difference between your rotation matrix and the one in the wikipedia link, you should probably consider the difference between an active and passive view of rotations. In this link you can see another example of the rotation of a vector field: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912070/rotating-vector-functions?rq=1

Comment: @Diego Yes exactly, I am dealing with passive transformations (I need to change the frame of reference in order to calculate my function, then change back again). Is there a way to write all this formally, to help see it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really know what you mean by "formally". To help see it I would play around with simple examples with pen and paper. This things are not really conceptually complicated, but it can be quite messy to get everything correct.